# The Request could not submitted for background process

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Error in File C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\POC1 {EFC98CD9-964C-4683-96BA-E02D634AF240}.rpt: The request could not be submitted for background processing.

vb code:
        Dim objReport As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass
        Dim location As String = context.Server.MapPath("../POC/POC1.rpt")
        objReport.FileName = location
        objReport.Load()
        objReport.SetDataSource(dsPOC)

```
    'dsPOC' is a dataset which contains tables

    Dim oStream As System.IO.Stream
    **oStream = objReport.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)**
    Dim streamLen As Integer = oStream.Length
    Dim arrPOCData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLen) {}
    oStream.Read(arrPOCData, 0, streamLen)

    Dim newDoc As New Doc
    newDoc.Read(arrPOCData)
    finalDoc.Append(newDoc)
    objReport.Dispose()
    dsPOC.Dispose()
```

Then
    I got this exception at objReport.ExportTostream(....).  I have tried few scenarios from i read up on website. None of them ones seems to be cause for my case. The scenarios are:
1.  Suppress blank Sub report - http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rjdudley/archive/2005/10/26/13443.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage
2.  Increase stack size - http://forums.asp.net/t/1647034.aspx/1?Crystal+Reports+Error+The+request+could+not+be+submitted+for+background+processing+
3.  Checked unique identifier in Dataset 
4.  Added new dll in system32 - http://www.mujpvs.cz/mujpvs/soubory/CR/readme.pdf, 
5.  Permissions have given to NETWORK SERVICES - http://forums.asp.net/p/1010099/2931117.aspx

Please help me to fix this.. three days i'm sitting with this.

Thanks in advance
saj,

Answer (score 0):

try `objReport.Load(location)` and see if that helps as I think `objReport.FileName` should be read only if not check the value of `location` in the debugger to make sure its set correctly.

edit: I checked and ther is a "set" method but it should only be a file name, not a full path as you are sending, `Load(location)` is safer as well as taking full path.

Comment: by the way I use C++ so am working this out from my knowledge of the API so YMMV

Comment: thanks for your reply: But it works for other records only two records getting this exception. anyway i'll check let you know

Comment: I'm getting this error for random records. When this line coming to execute objReport.Load() there is a .rpt file created in temp(c:windows/temp) folder. So tell me where i'm wrong

Comment: are there any subreports in those reports?